# Windows Fonts and Colors on HDTV (Plasma)

Tags: windows-7, fonts, kodi, plasma-tv

I've noticed that my fonts are difficult to read and the colors look a little bit off on my plasma TV connected to a windows 7 or windows 8 computer. I've adjusted the resolution and size of the fonts, however it's very difficult to browse the web on my TV, even for a few moments.

While I understand that TVs aren't optimized for Fonts & Applications, I'm wondering if there are some settings I can change to make it more bearable.

I want to emphasize that I have no issue with playing videos from the computer , or using specially designed 10-foot interfaces like XBMC. BUt if I have to switch to a desktop application, it's just painful to use.

Some computer monitors have a setting "optimize for video" vs "optimize for desktop". The problem I'm having seems like it's the TV or computer set to "optimize for video" and I don't know how to change it.

I have attached some photos of my TV's display to shed some light perhaps on how stuff is being displayed at the pixel level.
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: are you setting your video out to the native resolution of your TV?  How are you sending video out?  HDMI?

Comment: HDMI, native resolution 1080p 60Hz

Comment: Must know the model of tv? Many "TVs" are 720 only. also tvs have made provisions for underscan and overscan, aspect and all, and are not always pix=pix. while this works good for movies even computer played ones. Also grafics cards often have specific adjustements for HDMI outputs to adjust for a tv often unnessiarily. There are monitor "test" programs that will do single pixel lines, you might fire up one of those, or draw some single pixel non-aliased lines, and see if you have any interpolation going on first.  Another issue in font rendering is cleartype sub pixel aliasing.

Comment: Ahh pictures, that is just nasty :-)  you have big multi pixel color ghosting, like the subpixel anti-aliasing is conflicting with the TVs own rendering engine. Both trying to make a good picture, and together making a mess. I guess first try and adjust your cleartype tuning "cttune.exe" when displayed on the tv in question.

Comment: What is outputting the HDMI out of the computer?

Comment: panasonic plasma p54s1, nvidia 410m laptop HDMI, windows 8.1. I played with cleartype tuner, but obviously I didn't try all the settings. It's probably not _just_ fonts.

Comment: That looks like a TV software/hardware quality issue to me. Most TVs just aren't good enough  to be used as monitors. My LG 50PK790 is old, but has a special PC input setting, everything looks nice and crisp.